# how to store background-image url value in a variable

Tags: javascript, html

how to store background-image url value in a variable.

like

```
 image:url(images/9XkFhM8tRiuHXZRCKSdm_ny-2.jpg);
```

i store these `value = images/9XkFhM8tRiuHXZRCKSdm_ny-2.jpg` in a variable and use this variable href tag.

```
<div class="fill" style="background-image:url(images/9XkFhM8tRiuHXZRCKSdm_ny-2.jpg);"></div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/n1j4utuc/ Use this

Comment: i want only images/9XkFhM8tRiuHXZRCKSdm_ny-2.jpg value not a full value of background-image with url

Comment: <a href="" class="over">
                         <div class="fill" style="background-image:url(images/9XkFhM8tRiuHXZRCKSdm_ny-2.jpg);"></div>
      </a>                                                                                and get value fill href tag automatically

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var img_string = "image:url(images/9XkFhM8tRiuHXZRCKSdm_ny-2.jpg);";
var result = img_string.substring(img_string .indexOf('(') + 1, img_string .indexOf(')'));
alert(result); // will return only string between `(` and `)`
```

Comment: What is the error that it shows? Or it simply doesn't runs the `alert` ?

Comment: i have no error and nothing show http://themeforest.net/item/foundry-multipurpose-html-variant-page-builder/full_screen_preview/11562108 u see this link and build a webpage this site and insert gallery section in canvas and i want this type gallery ui function when i change online image when href value auto select same address..

Comment: @GauravSingh what? I did not understood a thing. By the way you want to get the `url` from the `div` element right?

Comment: Have a look at my answer, I have edited it as it contained unwanted characters which made it doesn't work.

Comment: I make this code : $('.over').attr('href',function(){
   var bg_img = $('fill').css("background-image");
   bg_img = bg_img.replace(/.*\s?url\([\'\"]?/, '').replace(/[\'\"]?\).*/, '');
   return bg_img;
  });                                                                                                                               <a href="" class="over">
                         <div class="fill bg-change" style="background-image:url(images/J3URHssSQyqifuJVcgKu_Wald.jpg)"></div>
      </a>

Comment: yes does it work but i have a another problem i make for column in html but when i am change the background image in a first div href take auto link but another 3 column href att. take same value and i want every hret take child background-image url address

Comment: I understand what you want, but I need you to explain a little more and provide a little more of code, as: where/what you are going to click and where you are going to change with the value you have.

Comment: you give me some guidance what can i do now :(

Comment: <a href="" class="over">
                         <div class="fill bg-change" style="background-image:url(images/cA4aKEIPQrerBnp1yGHv_IMG_9534-3-2.jpg);"></div>
</a> i have 4 tag in row but when i change backgroun-image in first div href att value will be change in all href att value changed so i want href att take a child value in a tag

Comment: post the javascript code you are using in your question so I can see it properly

Comment: <div class="col-md-3 margin-bottom-20"><a href="" class="over"><div class="fill bg-change" style="background-image:url(123jpg);"></div></a></div><div class="col-md-3 margin-bottom-20"><a href="" class="over"><div class="fill bg-change" style="background-image:url(1234.jpg);"></div></a></div> $('.over').attr('href',function(e){var bg_img = $('.fill').css("background-image");bg_img = bg_img.replace(/.*\s?url\([\'\"]?/, '').replace(/[\'\"]?\).*/, '');return bg_img;});

Comment: post in your question, not here in the comments

Comment: title = change href value accroding to child